# Java forcing default return statement from method with enum switch with all enum values covered

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, return

I have the following example situation:

```
public void shouldReturnStringForEnum() {
    MessageType myType = getType();
    System.out.println(getMessageForType(myType));
}

String getMessageForType(MessageType myType) {
    switch(myType) {
        case error:
            return "Error type";
        case warning:
            return "Warning type";
        case info:
            return "Info type";
    }
} // <= error: missing return statement

MessageType getType() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return MessageType.values()[random.nextInt(3)];
}

enum MessageType {error, warning, info }
```

I can't figure out what is the possibility to return from method `getMessageForType` in other way than from the body of `switch` statement.
I was thinking about:

- de-serialization from I/O data - but then `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant` happen long before call to `getMessageForType`
- possible null method parameter - but then it will fail on `switch(myType)` evaluation with `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Forcing a default return statement is uncomfortable in such situations, because I don't know what to return here. Throwing an exception in such case also has no sense here. What is the design decision behind such behaviour?

Please help, what am I missing here?

Comment: Some other thoughts: A) why use an enum when you then switch to derive a string from that? Why not *build* that string into your enum, so you can go `myType.getWhateverText()`?! B) a test annotated with @Test that doesn't do an **assert** or other kind of real verify ... but just a *print* ... isn't a test ;-)

Comment: hi, the return type doesn't matter here, and the @Test was just a form to play with this particular situation. I'll remove it for no confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Java forcing default return statement from method with enum switch with all enum values covered...   What is the design decision behind such behaviour?

This is a very important (and correct) decision made by the language.  Even though your current code handles all of the current values of the enum, that doesn't mean that the enum class might change long after your code is compiled.  You might upgrade a 3rd party library and it might add another enum value causing your code to be invalid at runtime without the default.

Even if you control the enum code that doesn't mean that another developer (or future you) might add another value to the enum and fail to update the switch statement.  Writing code that is forward compatible in this manner is generally a best practice and in this case critical for the language to force the behavior.

> I don't know what to return here.

The question then comes down to whether to throw an exception or not.  How to handle the invalid enum value or other exceptional conditions is something that we as programmers struggle with daily.  In this case, you need to ask yourself what you want to happen?  Is it an annoyance that shouldn't throw or is it a more critical error?  Should the caller handle the exception or is a `RuntimeException` ok?  These are questions you need to answer within the context of your application.

Lastly, I don't know about you, but most programmers I know cut&paste a lot of code.  Although this enum may never be expanded, future enums *will* be expanded and making a good decision may benefit from appropriately handling this case.

> Forcing a default return statement is uncomfortable in such situations...

`"Unknown type"` might be a good choice.

```
case ...:
     return ...;
default:
     // here in case someone updates the enum and forgets to update this code
     return "Unknown type";
```

> Throwing an exception in such case also has no sense here.

This depends a bit on how big a deal returning the default `"unknown"` string is.  In the case that there is a new enum with a missing case entry, would you want it to throw an exception or not?

For exceptions, you might want to use:

```
case ...:
     return ...;
default:
     throw new IllegalStateException("unknown enum type found for" + mType);
```

or maybe `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: Well I would expect that the error occurs after I extended the enum values not covering that in my switch statement. Basing on the answers here, I'm concluding that there is no other way to return from this method, without extending the enum. And that it is just a case of the interpreter, which simply doesn't "know" about the enum values.

Comment: Sorry I can't really parse you comments.  If you have added elements to the enum (I don't think the word "extended" should be used here), then your code will certainly compile fine.  The class certainly "knows" about the enum values, it's just that your _code_ does not take future values into account.  It's not about the interpreter.  Otherwise I don't get your point.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you edit the enum later, adding a new constant, without recompiling the switch?  That's the case being guarded against.

It's perfectly normal to write `default: throw new AssertionError();`.

Comment: It would be intuitive for me that adding new value to the enum type would result in compilation error. In fact I am throwing exception in such situations, but it was bugging me for some time why the interpreter doesn't "know" I covered all the scenarios, that maybe there is a scenario I'm not aware of.

Comment: If it is possible for the situation to arise where there is an unknown enum then I feel that the code should handle that appropriately.  A RuntimeException at the very least should be thrown.  Errors are typically not handled well by most code (catch Throwable anyone?) so it just seems like a cop-out to use an assert (or in this case throwing its error) here.

Comment: Why would you want it to be handled by most code, instead of erroring out immediately?

Comment: Because I expect the code to be fault tolerant.  Or I'm writing a library used by others.  Any number of reasons why I would want to do good defensive programming and not have my application error out immediately.

Answer (score 2):

> Throwing an exception in such case also has no sense here.

It makes sense because even if you know/think that you will never enter here, you have to handle this case to make your code compliant to the Java compilation rules that expect that the method return a `String` in any case.

You could spare the exception throw but it would make your code less robust :

```
String getMessageForType(MessageType myType) {
   switch(myType) {
     case error:
        return "Error type";
     case warning:
        return "Warning type";       
   }
   return "Info type";
 }
```

Suppose a `fine` enum value is added and you didn't update `getMessageForType()` you will return  "Info type" instead of.

So this is a fine approach :

```
String getMessageForType(MessageType myType) {
   switch(myType) {
      case error:
        return "Error type";
    case warning:
        return "Warning type";
    case info:
        return "Info type";
   }
   throw new RuntimeException("Should not happen here ! We get the enum value " + myType);
 }
```

And a better approach would be to add the `String` associated to each enum as an instance field of the enum :

```
enum MessageType {

 ERROR("Error type"), WARNING("Warning type"), INFO("Info type");

  private String msg;

  MessageType(String msg){ 
    this.msg = msg;
  }

  public String getMsg(){
     return msg;
  }
}
```

In this way you don't need any longer the `switch` as well as the `getMessageForType()` method.
The `shouldReturnStringForEnum()` method could be as simple as :

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnStringForEnum() {
    System.out.println(getType().getMsg());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `return` a default value out of the `switch` statement by using the `default` case of it, like this:

```
String getMessageForType(MessageType myType) {
    switch(myType) {
        case error:
            return "Error type";
        case warning:
            return "Warning type";
        case info:
            return "Info type";
        default:
            return "unknown message type";
    }
} // <= no error anymore
```

You could alternatively define a default value in a `String` before the `switch` statement and return that as default in case of no match in the `switch`:

```
String getMessageForType(MessageType myType) {
    String r = "unknown message type";
    switch(myType) {
        case error:
            r = "Error type";
        case warning:
            r = "Warning type";
        case info:
            r = "Info type";
    }
    return r;
} // <= no error anymore
```

Comment: But what the clients of such method would do with "unknown message type"? If I wanted to have an unknown message type, I would represent it in my enum values. I think throwing an exception is better choice given there is no awareness of possible enum values in the compile time

Comment: Sure, either clients have a way to handle *Unknown Message Type* or you just throw an `AssertionError`, a `RuntimeException` or similar...